# Archive manager not opening

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files, files, user-interface, file-management

I wanted to extract from .zip file, some files, and I pressed right click on file, as per usual, "Extract Here" and it doesn't do anything, I've tried again and again.. nothing.

In terminal:

```
file-roller: error while loading shared libraries: libmagic.so.1:
 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

I remember that I removed that file "libmagic.so.1" by mistake, and I didn't knew what will happen, now I know. The problem is how I recover that file?

P.S.: Sorry for my bad english.

Edit: I found the answer,
I've tried to run this code:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libmagic1
```

And it works!
Thanks!
You can close this topic.

Comment: Open panthon-files in the folder of your zip, open a terminal and try: file-roller -h yourfile.zip,  where yourfile.zip is the file you want to unzip. Edit your question and paste the output

Comment: file-roller: error while loading shared libraries: libmagic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
Yeah, I removed that file "libmagic.so.1", I've made a mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try from terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install libmagic-dev
```

Comment: The same error:
file-roller: error while loading shared libraries: libmagic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory